# How to add active marker on menu in Drupal Bootstrap 7.x-2.2

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, drupal, drupal-theming

I'm trying to add a triangle on the "active" element on the menu. I've added this css:

```
.navbar .active::after {
content: "";
position: absolute;
bottom: -16px;
border-width: 0px 15px 15px;
border-style: solid;
border-color: #ffffff transparent;
display: block;
width: 0;
}
```

But for some reason I'm getting 2 triangles slightly ontop of eachother on active elements as per attached screenshot. I don't know how else to get it right....please help?

Comment: No screenshot attached, you may need to link of to imgur or something.  Also, some HMTL code would be helpful.  Are you sure there aren't 2 active items, e.g. a parent and child?  Finally, I'd use single `:` for greater browser support (<IE8)

Answer (score 0):

andregriffin over on Drupal.org answered my question "
It's probably because there are two nested elements, both with the .active class, such as the li and the a tag. You need to be more specific on which one you are applying CSS to. you should probably use 
    .navbar > .active:after or .navbar a.active:after or .navbar li.active:after."

So I ended up with the following CSS and it works perfect!
    /* Active caret */
    .navbar a.active:after {
    content: "";
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    padding-top: 2px;
    border-width: 0px 10px 10px;
    border-style: solid;
    border-color: #ffffff transparent;
    display: block;
    width: 0;
    }